# dictデータの条件分岐処理とネットワークデータ属性値の更新

Tags: python, python3, networkx

Jupyter NotebookでPython3を使用しています。
ネットワークの作成、計算にはNetworkXを使用しています。

ネットワークグラフGについて、
エッジをkeyとする、辞書型データdict_1、dict_2、dict_3があります。

dict_1:エッジのタイプの辞書型データ
dict_2:エッジの評価値の辞書型データ
dict_3:エッジの長さの辞書型データ

dict_1の属性値(v1)がtype2の場合に、
dict_2の属性値(v2)が正の場合は、dict_3の属性値(v3)に10を足し、
dict_2の属性値(v2)が負の場合は、dict_3の属性値(v3)から10を引き、
dict_3を更新したいです。

そして更新されたdict_3を使用して、
グラフGのエッジの属性値（'length'）を書き換えたいと考えています。
下記のコードで試行錯誤をしていますが、
まず、dict_3を更新するところができていません。
また、dict_3からグラフGのエッジの属性値を書き換えようとすると、
すべて同じ値になってしまいます。

pythonはじめ、コーディングは初心者で、
初歩的間違いをしている可能性がありますが、なかなか解決策が見つからず困っています。
アドバイスを頂けると助かります。

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,3),(3,2),(3, 4),(3, 5)])
nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.show()

dict_1 = {(1,3):'type1', (3,2):'type1', (3, 4):'type2',  (3, 5):'type3'}
dict_2 = {(1,3):0, (3,2):0, (3, 4):-2, (3, 5):0}
dict_3 = {(1,3):10, (3,2):5, (3, 4):60, (3, 5):100}

nx.set_edge_attributes(G, dict_3, 'length')

print(G.edges.data('length'))
```

[(1, 3, 10), (3, 2, 5), (3, 4, 60), (3, 5, 100)]

```
for v1 in dict_1.values():
    if v1 == 'type2':
        for v2 in dict_2.values():
            for v3 in dict_3.values():
                for (u, v) in dict_3.keys():
                    if v2>0:
                        v3 = v3+10
                        dict_3[u, v]=v3
                    elif v2<0:
                        v3 = v3-10
                        dict_3[u, v]=v3
                    else:
                        break
print(dict_3.values())
```

dict_values([10, 5, 60, 100])

```
for (u, v) in dict_3.keys():
    for le in dict_3.values():
        G.edges[u, v]['length'] = le

print(G.edges.data('length'))
```

[(1, 3, 100), (3, 2, 100), (3, 4, 100), (3, 5, 100)]

Comment: `NetworkX` とは LAN TCP/IP のネットワークとは違うので, `network` タグは違うのではないかと

Comment: network タグを外しました。紛らわしく、失礼いたしました。

Comment: (stackoverflow歴は私も短いのですが …) 十分な回答ならば承認済みという項目があるようです。未だ待つことも可能。同じ質問の延長なら情報継ぎ足す感じで https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: すみません、今回が初めての質問で勝手が分かっておりませんでした。問題は解決しているので、承認済みとさせていただきました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict_3` の更新は, 同じエッジ(のキー) に対してデータを取得・更新する必要があるはずです
(このキー, エッジをとりあえず `eg` 変数として扱う)

```py
for eg in dict_3.keys():
    v1 = dict_1[eg]
    v2 = dict_2[eg]

    if v1 == 'type2':
      if v2>0:
          dict_3[eg] += 10
      elif v2<0:
          dict_3[eg] -= 10

print(dict_3)
```

`+=` の部分は `dict_3[eg] = dict_3[eg] + 10` と同等, `-=` も同じ

---

グラフ, というか属性書き換えは, もとの処理にもあるようこれでよいのでは？

```py
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, dict_3, 'length')
```

ループで行うには, (たぶん)このような処理 (…目的が一致してるか不明なので)

```py
for k, v in dict_3.items():
    G.edges[k]['length'] = v
```

Comment: 早速ありがとうございます！アドバイス通りに書き換えたところ、目的の処理ができるようになりました。大変助かりました。